# How to prevent body to receive focus when .blur method was called on a element?

Tags: javascript, html

Why browsers do not track the focusable elements, so that when we call `blur` on some element, the element, which was focused before, receives focus, and not the `body`?

Assume, there are several focus-capable elements on the page. The first one should be focused on load. Setting `autofocus` handles this. Later on some event we manually focus the second element, and again, later, on some other event, we blur that *second* element. The expected behaviour would be that previous focused element receives focus. But actually the body element gets activated (`document.activeElement === document.body`)

Setting `<body tabindex=-1>` has no effect.

Here is a simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9oenrguv/ The behaviour I would expect is: when we click the button, after a second the first input is focused, but instead body element is focused, though the first input was previously focused and also has autofocus attribute. Could somebody please explain, why body is focused, and if there is any way to prevent this?

Is the manual tracking of the previous active element is the only one way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you write "*expected behavior*", do you mean "my (your...) *required* behavior"?

Comment: @Amit, Yes, but i would better say "**Logically** expected", or do I miss something?

Comment: Asking every browser to always track an infinite trail (because you could .blur, .blur, .blur) of what has had focus doesn't seem like a good usage of processing power.  Especially given the fact that you could add or remove items from the DOM at any time. 

Writing it yourself ("manually tracking") makes sure that it works for your particular case and would also give you the flexibility to add other business logic if you desired.  Maybe(?) there is a library out there that provides a framework to help automate it.  If not, please write yours flexibly and open source it!

Comment: You are right, but that's almost common undo problem. And even without tracking auf the focused elements, why not just to focus the element with autofocus instead of body element, see my example.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it clear you're asking how to achieve your requirements, instead of "ranting" about how things work.

Comment: @Amit, I'm just asking why the things are working as they do. As for me it is not logical, that's why not expected. But when you can explain, why from the example the body element gets focused instead of the `autofocused` first input, then please do this.

Comment: I don't know why, but I honestly don't usually bother to contemplate on such issues. That's the way things work, there isn't anything I can do about it (suppose it bothered my like it bothers you), so I don't see the point. You might just as well ask why certain named colors exist, or why others don't, but that's just the way it is...

Comment: this is old, but wrap in a `if (!document.body) /* ... */`